# objective C - how to remove "Quick Look" this menu item in DocumentInteraction?

Tags: ios

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4447651/problem1.JPG

Above is the button which I want to remove.

I do not want user to use this "Quick look" function. If there are no suitable apps, I show a alert msg. Even if some apps is detected by UIDocumentInteractionController, I still do want user to click "Quick look"

Can anybody tell me a solution pls???

Comment: I find the solution finally....

use "presentOpeninmenu"....

Comment: Could you please describe your solution here in more detail? Thanks!